# How to use "CFRetain(sampleBuffer)" in Swift?

Tags: swift, avfoundation

How to use "CFRetain(sampleBuffer)" and "CFRelease(sampleBuffer)" in Swift?
[image]
`CFRetain is unavailable: Core Foundation objectes are automatically memory managed.`

```
 - (void)captureOutput:(AVCaptureOutput *)captureOutput didOutputSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer fromConnection:(AVCaptureConnection *)connection 
{

    [self appendVideoSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];

}

- (void)appendVideoSampleBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef)sampleBuffer
{
    dispatch_async( _writingQueue, ^{

        CFRetain(sampleBuffer);
        [_videoInput appendSampleBuffer:sampleBuffer];
        CFRelease(sampleBuffer);

    });
}
```

> If you need to reference the CMSampleBuffer object outside of the scope of this method, you must CFRetain it and then CFRelease it when you are finished with it. 
>   ([Apple Document](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avcapturevideodataoutputsamplebufferdelegate/1385775-captureoutput))

Comment: Do you _need_ to "reference the CMSampleBuffer object outside of the scope of this method"?

Comment: Yes, I want to `appendSampleBuffer` in `_writingQueue `.

Comment: What does `appendSampleBuffer:`  do with the buffer? Does it copy its contents to some other memory that it owns, or does it use it as-is? In the first case, your retain/release pair shouldn't be necessary I think.

Comment: On a second thought, not sure _when_ your async block is executed, so perhaps you need to put the `retain` _outside_ the `dispatch_async()` call, to make sure that the buffer has not been deallocated when the closure is executed. The `release` should stay inside the block.

Comment: In either case, the document is telling you that just by being passed the buffer, your code does _not_ automatically obtain ownership of it, and if you intend to keep it around for a while (i.e., after the method exits), you should retain it to claim ownership (and release it to relinquish ownership once you are done. **This is very important to avoid memory leaks**).

Comment: Thanks, NicolasMiari. For security, I also want to use `retain ` and `release`,  but **CFRetain is unavailable in Swift**. I don't know how to cover `CFRetain(sampleBuffer)` and `CFRelease(sampleBuffer)`.

Comment: I'm not completely up-to-date, but I think it is unavailable because now, in Swift, Core Foundation too is automatically managed (ARC) (see this blog post: http://ericasadun.com/2015/05/28/swift-five-things-about-core-foundation/). So, perhaps Apple's docs are outdated (or apply only to Objective-C). I suggest you search for the latest info regarding ARC

Answer (score 11):

According to  [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/working_with_core_foundation_types)

**Memory Managed Objects**

> Core Foundation objects returned from annotated APIs are automatically
> memory managed in Swift—you do not need to invoke the CFRetain,
> CFRelease, or CFAutorelease functions yourself.
>
> If you return Core Foundation objects from your own C functions and
> Objective-C methods, you can annotate them with either the
> CF_RETURNS_RETAINED or CF_RETURNS_NOT_RETAINED macro to automatically
> insert memory management calls. You can also use the
> CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_ENABLED and CF_IMPLICIT_BRIDGING_DISABLED macros
> to enclose C function declarations that follow Core Foundation
> ownership policy naming policy in order to infer memory management
> from naming.
>
> If you use only annotated APIs that do not indirectly return Core
> Foundation objects, you can skip the rest of this section. Otherwise,
> continue on to learn about working with unmanaged Core Foundation
> objects.

Comment: I can't find the quoted text in the provided link

Comment: @Francescu here's the updated link:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/imported_c_and_objective-c_apis/working_with_core_foundation_types

Answer (score 1):

You just need to `sampleBuffer = nil` to manually release.
But it's recommended to copy pointer before using it
`CMSampleBufferCreateCopy(kCFAllocatorDefault, sampleBuffer, &newBuffer)`.

In this case set `newBuffer` to nil before creating copy of new `sampleBuffer`.